# Training a Neural Network using a Discriminator Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm working on a project where I want to train a neural network using another neural network as the discriminator. I already made a discriminator model that can distinguish between different sets of data but now I'm stuck on how to train the new neural network using it. I'm not an expert in this field so if anyone has any tips or know of any techniques I should use to accomplish this, that would be great. Also, are there any specific libraries or frameworks that are recommended for this type of task? I'm just trying to figure out the best way to approach this. Thanks in advance for any help!

So far this is all I've come up with for the discriminator model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Define image data generator for both real and fake images
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)

dataset_path = "../training/discriminator"

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(dataset_path,
                                              target_size=(150, 150),
                                              class_mode='binary',
                                              subset='training')

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(dataset_path,
                                              target_size=(150, 150),
                                              class_mode='binary',
                                              subset='validation')

# Create the neural network model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_generator, 
          epochs=15, 
          validation_data=validation_generator, 
          steps_per_epoch=500,
          validation_steps=5000)

model.save("../model/discriminator")
```

Though I haven't gotten past making the discriminator. I have no idea of what to do, and I haven't had much success searching online. I need all the help I can get.

Comment: The new model you are training, what is its purpose? Another discriminator network? Classification?

Comment: I'm trying out image generation, I am aware that it is difficult but I still want to do it, I already know how I'm going to generate the image, I just need help training it using the discriminator that I created.